# Convert PHP Date to Time

Tags: php, datetime, date, time

How can I covert this PHP date string:

```
Thu 19th Aug 2010 @ 7:52PM
```

to this:

```
1282247549
```

Which is done by:

```
gmdate("D jS M Y @ g:iA", $row['project_deadline'])
```

The timestamp is from the database with the stored `time()` function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can parse that string into a UNIX timestamp with the [`strtotime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function:

```
$str = 'Thu 19th Aug 2010 @ 7:52PM';
$str = str_replace('@', '', $str);

$timestamp = strtotime($str);
```

Comment: Uh, that was 41 minutes ago ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you have unstandard format, then you should use [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) :

```
$str = 'Thu 19th Aug 2010 @ 7:52PM';
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('!D jS M Y @ g:iA', $str);
echo $dt->getTimestamp();
```